# Inherited Property is nothing inside a method of the base class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, properties

Let's take the following case

```
Public MustInherit Class AnexaClass
    Inherits ObjectBase
    Private _proprietar As New ProprietarClass
    Public Property proprietar As ProprietarClass
        Get
            Return _proprietar
        End Get
        Set(value As ProprietarClass)
            _proprietar = value
            OnPropertyChanged("proprietar")
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Anexa3Class
    Inherits AnexaClass

    Private _Proprietari As New ObservableCollection(Of ProprietarClass)
    Public Property Proprietari As ObservableCollection(Of ProprietarClass)
        Get
            Return _Proprietari
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ProprietarClass))
            _Proprietari = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Proprietari")
            If _Proprietari.Count > 0 Then
                Me.proprietar = _Proprietari(0) 'this line sets Proprietar to be the same as the first item of Proprietari and it works as it should be
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

Public MustInherit Class AnexaViewModel(Of AnexaT As {AnexaClass, New})
    Inherits ObjectBase

    Private _Anexa As New AnexaT
    Public Property Anexa As AnexaT
        Get
            Return _Anexa
        End Get
        Set(value As AnexaT)
            _Anexa = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Anexa")
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub ToXML()
        MsgBox(Anexa.proprietar.nume) 'at this point Anexa.proprietar is nothing
        MsgBox(Anexa.Proprietari(0).nume) ' but this is fine, even though Proprietari is only declared inside the derived class Anexa3Class
        ''Some other code''
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Anexa3ViewModel
    Inherits AnexaViewModel(Of Anexa3Class)
End Class
```

My program instantiate `Anexa3ViewModel`, then it sets `Proprietari property` which sets `Proprietar` to be `Proprietari(0)` (when I debug, this seems to work correctly), then I call `ToXML` by pressing a button through commanding. Inside `ToXML` `Anexa.proprietar` is nothing, but `Anexa.Proprietari(0)` has the correct value.

Apparently `proprietar` property lost its value, or there are two `Proprietar` Properties stored, one for my base class and one for the derived class. I thought this is possible only by shadowing a base property, which I'm not doing. I think there is some inheritance notion that I fail to understand.

Could someone shed some light on this please?

**Clarifications1**: I know that `Proprietari`'s setter doesn't get fire if I simply add an item to the collection. This is not my problem as I set the whole collection at once and its setter gets fired and I can see that `proprietar` gets the correct value of `Proprietari(0)`. The problem is that it is loosing its value when it gets to `ToXML`.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: noted. At least I used tags correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your application, the best guess is that you have other code adding values to the Proprietari collection in the Anexa3Class rather than setting the entire collection through the property.

There are a few potential workarounds to this, depending on your application needs and design. One way is to handle the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event on the Proprietari collection:

```
Private WithEvents _Proprietari As New ObservableCollection(Of ProprietarClass)
Private Sub _Proprietari_CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles _Proprietari.CollectionChanged
    If Me.proprietar Is Nothing AndAlso e.Action = Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add Then
        Me.proprietar = e.NewItems(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Another potential option is be to change propietar to an overridable readonly property and always return the 0th value, but that would potentially defeat the OnPropertyChanged logic.

Comment: You answered one of my unasked question. I needed a way to update proprietar whenever I add an item toproprietari, and I was looking into CollectionChanged right now, but this isn't the actual problem stated. I don't understand why adding items to  Proprietari collection would change proprietar value, once it has been set, when Proprietari collection had been set(I'm actually setting it as a whole through deserialization). So my problem isn't why proprietar is not updating, but why its value is nothing inside ToXML method when there isn't any other code to change proprietar value.

Comment: @Andrei: I think the issue is that somehow, proprietar is being set to Nothing after you set the Proprietari collection. If you are setting the properties through deserialization, then the issue is likely that the collection is set before the object (i.e. set Proprietari then set Proprietar). I would do one of two things depending on how hard it is to reproduce: 1) in debug mode, set a breakpoint in the proprietar setting and see when it is set to Nothing; 2) if debug isn't possible, add code to the setter to test the value and thrown an exception when it is Nothing, then use stack trace.

Comment: You were right, the problem was the deserialization. I'll edit your response and mark it as answered.